# Capitalization of "diploma business informatics"

Tags: orthography, capitalization, business-language

For an application I need to translate my resume. What is the right way spelling of my degree:

1. 2010-2015 Diploma business informatics
2. 2010-2015 Diploma Business Informatics
3. 2010-2015 Diploma of Business Informatics

Comment: Diploma in Business Informatics, because unlike a Master, you get a Diploma in a particular course.

Comment: Are you sure - if I google for "Diploma in Business Informatics", results for "Diploma of Business Informatics" show up, e.g.: http://www.canberra.edu.au/future-students/courses/pathways/international-students/diplomas/diploma-of-business-informatics

Comment: Alright, in that case, the 3rd option is what you need. Diploma of Business Informatics.